# add user subscription to multiple roles in MS Azure

Tags: azure, azure-role-environment

I'm adding users to MS Azure subscriptions. And it looks to me as if you can only add one role to one subscription at a time. Is it possible to add multiple roles to one subscription at the same time?

Comment: elaborate please? how are you adding those?

Comment: For sure he means setting this up using the portal... @bluethundr: did you find a way?